# Installing Extention Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, extension

[image: Etention installation]
Hi
I'm trying to install Cartthrob 
I have Extension enabled 
But still carthrob is asking for extension to be installed

Is there anything else i need to check for this?

Thanks!

I'm testing this on ee 2.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not asking you to install it, it is telling you that the extension is going to be installed automatically with the module. In previous versions of EE you could sometimes install a module without installing the extension which would cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i was confused because my installation of CT gave errors i thought perhaps that is where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You might have extensions disabled globally.

Have a look underAdd-ons > Extensions, then look at the top right for an "Enable Extensions" button. If the button already says "Disable Extensions", then this isn't the problem.